# Magento2.4.5 pre-loading all products on category page, I just want to pre-load 10000 skus, like old version

Tags: magento2.4.5

I updated magento to the latest version 2.4.5, it will load all products on category page, but I have more than 60000 skus, it load very slow. how to limit pre-loading 10k skus likes old version? I tried to change search_request.xml file, but it's not working for me.

I always got error: `FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /aaa/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 292" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: pazdb.com, request: "GET /en_laptop/replacement-laptop-screens.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "www.aaa.com", referrer: "https://www.aaa.com/"`

whatever I changed memory_limit=-1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing slow loading times on your category page after updating Magento to version 2.4.5 and have a large number of SKUs, you can limit the number of pre-loaded SKUs to improve the page's loading speed. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Create a custom module or use an existing one.
2. In the module's di.xml file, add the following code:

   ```
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="pageSize" xsi:type="number">10000</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
   ```
3. Replace 10000 with the desired number of SKUs to pre-load, such as 5000.
4. Save the di.xml file and flush the Magento cache.

After following these steps, the category page will only pre-load the number of SKUs specified in the di.xml file. This should improve the page's loading speed, especially if you have a large number of SKUs.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I created di.xml in my custom module app/code/custom/default/etc/di.xml, re-deployed and reindexed, I also cleared all caches, but still loads all products.

Answer (score 0):

In new Magento version, the pager is build in the **SearchCriteriaResolver**

```
public function resolve(): SearchCriteria
{
    $searchCriteria = $this->builder->create();
    $searchCriteria->setRequestName($this->searchRequestName);
    $searchCriteria->setSortOrders($this->orders);
    $searchCriteria->setCurrentPage($this->currentPage - 1);
    if ($this->size) {
        $searchCriteria->setPageSize($this->size);
    }

    return $searchCriteria;
}
```

Change this function, the elasticsearch will return the total result which was configured in the search_request.xml

**File**: vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection/SearchCriteriaResolver.php:77

**The new function look like this:**

```
public function resolve(): SearchCriteria
{
    $searchCriteria = $this->builder->create();
    $searchCriteria->setRequestName($this->searchRequestName);
    $searchCriteria->setSortOrders($this->orders);
    $searchCriteria->setCurrentPage($this->currentPage - 1);
    return $searchCriteria;
}
```